# Reload div with javascript - Rails

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby, ajax

I'm creating a chat and I'd like to show the messages without reload the page.
My database is saving the messages, but I need reload the page to show them.

My index:

```
<div class="panel panel-default">
            <div class="panel-heading">
                Conversa com <%= @other.fullname %>
            </div>
            <div class="panel-body">
                <div class="container">

                    <%= form_for [@conversation, @conversation.messages.new], remote: true do |f| %>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <%= f.text_area :content, placeholder: "Escreva a mensagem", class: "form-control" %>
                        </div>
                        <%= f.hidden_field :user_id, value: current_user.id %>

                        <div class="actions">
                            <%= f.submit "Enviar mensagem", class: "btn btn-primary" %>
                        </div>
                    <% end %>

                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div id="chat">
            <%= render @messages, locals: {conversation: @conversation} %>
        </div>

    </div>
```

_messages.html.erb

```
<div class="panel" id="refresh">
    <div class="panel-body">
        <%= image_tag message.user.avatar.url, class: "img-circle avatar-small" %>
        <strong><%= message.user.fullname %></strong>

        <span class="pull-right"><%= message.message_time %></span>
        <br>
        <div class="row-space-2">
            <%= message.content %>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

messages controller

```
class MessagesController < ApplicationController
    before_action :authenticate_user!
    before_action :set_conversation

    def index
        if current_user == @conversation.sender || current_user == @conversation.recipient
            @other = current_user == @conversation.sender ? @conversation.recipient : @conversation.sender
            @messages = @conversation.messages.order("created_at DESC")
        else
            redirect_to conversations_path, alert: "Você não tem permissão para acessar essa página."
        end
    end

    def create
        @message = @conversation.messages.new(message_params)
        @messages = @conversation.messages.order("created_at DESC")

        if @message.save
            respond_to do |format|
                format.js
            end
        end
    end

    private

        def set_conversation
            @conversation = Conversation.find(params[:conversation_id])
        end

        def message_params
            params.require(:message).permit(:content, :user_id)
        end
end
```

model message.rb

```
class Message < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :conversation
  belongs_to :user

  validates_presence_of :content, :conversation_id, :user_id

  def message_time
    created_at.strftime("%v")
  end
end
```

How can I reload only the div refresh (_messages.html.erb) each 1 second, to show the new messages of the chat.

I'm learning RoR, so I'm sorry if I not described so clear what I want to do.

ps: for a couple of reasons I can't use WebSockets.

Comment: I think you may have chosen a wrong tool (RoR) in implementing live chat. It's more natural to implement it with node.js (which is born async) and websocket. You can have a look at `Action Cable` in RoR 5 if you insist in RoR.

Comment: If you can't use we sockets, you can set a browser interval that uses Ajax to ping the server for updates.